# Swapping the source of an image based on a boolean value

Tags: python, django

Here's my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
  thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

html template:

```
       {% for product in products %}
        {% if product.productimage_set.all %}
          {% for image in product.productimage_set.all %}
            {% if image.thumbnail %}
          <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          <img src="image template when no image at all">
        {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to use the image that has a "thumbnail" field equal to true by default, but if a `Product` have an image but none with "thumbnail" equal to true, it should use any image with foreign key that is matching this product, but if a product doesn't have any image then just use a template image.

I have tried using `{% else %}` after checking if image is a thumbnail, but If a product have more than one image, then it would show them all.

Comment: Is `product` in your template passed through the view context or is there another for loop that loops through the products that you did not show?

Comment: @gmdev yes there's another loop that I forgot to include. My view is just passing all products from the database to the template. I updated the the template code